# compare two strings in cocos 2D iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am getting ccString through the `obstInfo->name` . now i want to compare it with normal string "eagle".that means i have to compare CCString with normal string. in cocos 2D how to compare this.

I converted CCString to string through the `m_sString` &  tried belows way but giving error- EXC_bad_access.

```
 string eg="eagle";
      string na=obstInfo->name->m_sString;
        if( na.compare(eg)==0);
        {
      }
```

I googled it everywhere but didn't get correct one.

Comment: please mention the reason for down vote

Comment: I think there is no datatype called string in objective c

Comment: What about strcmp() ?

Comment: @Rao27: its cpp file, are you aware that in cocos 2d maxly cpp files are used

Comment: ok, so where did you mentioned it is .cpp file, And your question is not descriptive.
And yes i know there may .cpp file in cocos2d.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/25666

Answer (score 0):

To compare two string , Use below code

```
NSString *string1 = @"string1";
NSString *string2 = @"string1";


[string1 isEqualToString:string2]; //this will give true.
```

**EDITED:**
    Recently i was working with my teammates in **cocos2d-x** and at that time i face one situaltion in which i have to comopare two strings so i did like below:

```
CCString *str1 = new CCString("abc");
CCstring *str2 = new CCString("abc");
```

for comparing two strings i did like this:

```
str1.isEqual(str2);
```

or you can do like:

```
Str2.isEqual(new CCString("abc"));
```

Comment: its not .m file, it is cpp file

Comment: Yes, i got it.You have good attitude.You know what am i saying.

Comment: this is the correct form to compare 2 strings in objective-c, to use c++ code with objective-c you can use .mm file extension, change your file extension to .mm and try this code